# Convert Excel formula into VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following formula in an excel worksheet that I want to make a Macro:

```
IF(OR(AA2=2,AA2=3,AA2=4),"00",IF(AA2=5,"0"&LEFT(Z2,1),IF(AA2=6,LEFT(Z2,2))))
```

I want to establish this formula for a certain range based on another column.  I have multiple formulas written already that work to do this such as:

```
Range("B3:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Value = "=B2+1"
```

Basically I want to make the If/Or statement above work in VBA with the desired range.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to place the ***formula*** in some cells or the  ***result of the formula*** in some cells??

Comment: Have you tried, copy-pasting the formula in the desired range using a macro? Using fill-down is also an option that could help.

Comment: I want the result of the formula in the cells.. kind of like the second formula up there that returns the Value of B2+1

Comment: I am just struggling with 1) getting the IF Or statement to properly work and 2) to get it to be applied to the desired range

Comment: Two questions: 1) Do you want the formula in the cell to be something like `=MyFunction()` or `=MyFunction(AA2, Z2)` and for the vba code to calculate the result? and 2) are all the cell references relative to the current cell? - so for example in the next row the formula would be `=IF(OR(AA3=2,AA3=3,AA3=4),"00",IF(AA3=5,"0"&LEFT(Z3,1),IF(AA3=6,LEFT(Z3,2))))`?

Comment: John I want the cell reference to be the latter.... I want it to apply to the relative row as I go down... until I get to the Range that is set by column M

Comment: Post the code you have tried and identify what is failing

Comment: I deleted what I tried because it wouldn't work... I am not knowledgeable in IF/Or/and statements in VBA

Comment: Hmmm - - - Why don't you just use the formula that you have given, instead of the code `=B2+1`?

Comment: I think that might have worked.......

Answer (score 1):

Just setup your function, turn on the Macro Recorder, click on the cell that contains your function, hit F2 and hit Enter.  If you want to setup dynamic start and end rows, or columns, you can use the methodologies below.

```
Sub DynamicRange()
'Best used when only your target data is on the worksheet

'Refresh UsedRange (get rid of "Ghost" cells)
  Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

'Select UsedRange
  Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Select

End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub DynamicRange()
'Best used when first column has value on last row and first row has a value in the last column

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("D9")

'Find Last Row and Column
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range
  sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select

End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub DynamicRange()
'Best used when you want to include all data stored on the spreadsheet

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("D9")

'Refresh UsedRange
  Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

'Find Last Row and Column
  LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
  LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

'Select Range
  sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select

End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub DynamicRange()
'Best used when your data does not have any entirely blank rows or columns

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("D9")

'Select Range
  StartCell.CurrentRegion.Select

End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub DynamicRange()
'Best used when column length is static

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("D9")

'Refresh UsedRange
  Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

'Find Last Row
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Select Range
  sht.Range("D9:M" & LastRow).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have a dynamic range from Excel when the formula is entered via VBA as such:

```
Range( Cells(2,"AB"), Cells (colMVal, "AB")).Formula = "=IF(OR(AA2=2,AA2=3,AA2=4),""00"",IF(AA2=5,""0""&LEFT(Z2,1),IF(AA2=6,LEFT(Z2,2))))"
```

Note that the formula is entered into row 2 all the way down to the column M value to dictate the final row (colMVal).  Also note the double quotes WITHIN the formula.

If anything is required to be FIXED, rather than dynamic, you would use "$", such that:

```
Range( Cells(2,"AB"), Cells (colMVal, "AB")).Formula = "=IF(OR(AA$2=2,AA$2=3,AA$2=4),""00"",IF(AA$2=5,""0""&LEFT(Z$2,1),IF(AA$2=6,LEFT(Z$2,2))))"
```

Where I have locked that ALL references verify that the row is 2, hence AA$2.  As Excel fills the formula into each row of the desired range, it will dynamically assign the correct row.

Comment: So if I want this formula to be in Column AB, where would I put this in?

Comment: Surely it would be in the same place (UDF) that you have put `Range("B3:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Value = "=B2+1"`

Comment: ... substituting column AB instead of B. Mind you, it looks like it should start at row 2 rather than row 3.

Comment: @ZacharyDesgain Updated my post to reflect... the column in which the Range defines would be AB; the Cells(row,column) can accomodate not knowing the column number and can be shown as Cells(3,"AB").

Comment: @JohnRC I am skeptical to mess with starting on row 2 or row 3 given the two examples given are different.  I will rely on the OP to determine that and utilize the provided syntax appropriately.

Comment: @Cyril - Yes, that's a fair criticism. I was only inferring, perhaps incorrectly, that, while the formula used for column B refers to the cell above (simply to number the rows sequentially), the formula for column AB refers to different columns, so I guessed that the result in AB3 is more likely to be referring to other cells in the same row, rather than cells in the row above.